# OverflowException with NHibernate and Oracle SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY

Tags: .net, oracle, nhibernate, spatial, overflowexception

I'm getting an OverflowException when trying to query an SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY from an Oracle database with NHibernate.

The exception is thrown in Oracle.DataAcess in the `public static unsafe object GetValue(OracleConnection con, IntPtr pUdt, int attrIndex)` method of `OracleCustomTypeBase<T>` class.

From research I found that this seems to stem from the fact that Oracle uses higher precision than .NET for decimal values and thus crashes when pulling the values from the DB and converting them to the native .NET type.

I already tried modifying the code so it fetches `OracleDecimal` objects, set the precision and then get the `Value` property (returning a .NET decimal) – no luck.

What can I do to resolve this issue? Note that I cannot specify a mapping for a custom type, because I get the SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY from a stored procedure or by selecting from the fake `DUAL` table.

If there are any questions, I'll be glad to answer them.